# Tieing TFS Feedback To PBI

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Does anyone know if there a way to tie a feedback request from within TFS to a particular PBI work item? any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create a bug or backlog item **linked** to the feedback.

1. Open the Feedback click **All links**
2. Click the button as below picture
3. On the popup window, select *Link type*, *Work item type* and then
   add a *Title*

[image]